# Keras Tensor Flow Error : ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

It's my first time using Tensorflow and I have this code :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
# Task: predict whether each sentence is a question or not.
sentences = tf.constant(
    ['What makes you think she is a witch?',
     'She turned me into a newt.',
     'A newt?',
     'Well, I got better.'])
is_question = tf.constant([True, False, True, False])

# Build the Keras model.
keras_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None], ragged=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

keras_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
keras_model.fit(sentences, is_question, epochs=5)
test_loss, test_acc = keras_model.evaluate(sentences,  is_question)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

But when I try to use it I have this error :

```py
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Comment: Which is your prediction layer? , if it is  `tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)`, then it is incomplete.

Comment: What other parameters do I need to include ?

Comment: Is the last dimension of `sentence` ragged ? I think you can not feed tensors with the ragged last dimension to Dense layer

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What do you mean the last dimension of sentence ? And I tried to create something similar to an example of this page : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor @Andrey

Comment: try the model from your link. Your model will not work with ragged tensor (with the sentences of different lengths)

Comment: Ok thanks, I did it and it works but when i tried to add these line : 
`test_loss, test_acc = keras_model.evaluate(hashed_words,  is_question)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)`
It raised an error : `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with the code:

1. You need to specify the shape of the input layer.
2. You cannot feed raw text to a deep model. You need to tokenize it to integers.
3. (The one that actually raises mentioned error:) You cannot feed the model the input that has ragged last dimension. You need to pad the input with zeros to reach a constant sequence length.

for tokenizing and padding you can use the following code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=my_max)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text) 
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)   
sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length,
                                           truncating='post', padding='post')
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a function to automatically pad the input ?

Comment: And to tokenize it, I need this function : `tf.strings.to_hash_bucket_fast` ?

Comment: @AnatoleSot I added the code that may help you

Answer (score 1):

You can not use your model with tensor with ragged last dimension (where the lengths of sentences are different).